# LSTM without parameter sharing in Tensorflow/Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

We know that one of the features of LSTM is parameter sharing between different timesteps. I want to have LSTM without parameter (weight and bias) sharing. How can I implement this structure using Tensorflow and Keras?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NicolasGervais I haven't found any direct way to do this using Keras/Tensorflow until now.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by a LSTM "without parameters"? Can you may be draw a diagram explaining the difference between what you need and a standard LSTM.?